# How do I pass data from one SwiftUI view file to another?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parameter-passing

The basic gist is I'm building a meal planner app. I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI and this is my first project so I'm probably making a noob mistake lol Basically I want to pass the current index, which is a data object for a day and it's meals, to the DailyMealPlan view when I tap on the corresponding card. I don't get an error when I pass the currentDay variable to the view, but inside the second view file I'm not sure how I handle that data. I keep getting an error that "CurrentMealPlan is not in scope". I understand how scope works and I suspect I'm just missing something when it comes to passing the data into the second view.

ForEach code

```
ForEach(CurrentMealPlan.indices) { index in
                                    
  let currentDay = CurrentMealPlan[index]
    NavigationLink(
      destination: DailyMealPlan(DailyMealPlan: currentDay))
    {                                  
      MealPlanCard(
       Day: "\(CurrentMealPlan[index].DayTitle)",
       Breakfast: "\(CurrentMealPlan[index].Breakfast)",
       Lunch: "\(CurrentMealPlan[index].Lunch)",
       Dinner: "\(CurrentMealPlan[index].Dinner)"
      )
    }
}
```

DailyMealPlan view

```
struct DailyMealPlan: View {
    
    var DailyMealPlan: Day = CurrentMealPlan[index]
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                   
                    SingleMealCard(Meal: "Breakfast", CalCount: 500, MealInfo: "Meal info here")
                    
                    SingleMealCard(Meal: "Lunch", CalCount: 500, MealInfo: "Meal info here")
                    
                    SingleMealCard(Meal: "Dinner", CalCount: 500, MealInfo: "Meal info here")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CurrentMealPlan model

```
struct Day: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var Date: String
    var DayTitle: String
    var Breakfast: String
    var Lunch: String
    var Dinner: String
    
    
    init(id:Int=0,Date:String="",DayTitle:String="",Breakfast:String="",Lunch:String="",Dinner:String="") {
        self.id  = id
        self.Date = Date
        self.DayTitle = DayTitle
        self.Breakfast = Breakfast
        self.Lunch = Lunch
        self.Dinner = Dinner
    }
}

let CurrentMealPlan: [Day] = [
    Day(
        id: 0,
        DayTitle: "Sunday",
        Breakfast:"Oatmeal",
        Lunch: "Sandwich",
        Dinner: "Cheeseburger with Fries"
    )
]
```

Comment: Can you include your `CurrentMealPlan` model? It'll be easier to show what to do with access to that. By the way, it's common practice in Swift to capitalize type names, but leave variable/property names in lowercase.

Comment: Try just removing `= CurrentMealPlan[index]`.

Comment: @jnpdx Updated with that! Of course that's an array but for space sake I only included 1 day.

Comment: Did you try @aheze's suggestion? Looks like that might do it

Comment: @jnpdx I just did and holy cow I didn't realize it was that simple. As I stated I'm definitely a noob. I also wasn't properly passing the data to the preview which was part of the problem too. It works now, thank you both!

Comment: Thank you @aheze, that did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through your code. First, you declared the `CurrentMealPlan` array inside the parent view. It probably looks something like this:

```
@State var CurrentMealPlan = [Day]()
```

<sup>Note: As [jnpdx commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105842/how-do-i-pass-data-from-one-swiftui-view-file-to-another#comment120372767_68105842), you should lowercase property names like `var currentMealPlan` and `var dailyMealPlan`. Also, you **should not** have the same name for the `DailyMealPlan` view and the `DailyMealPlan` property... it's extremely confusing.</sup>

Your code is correct. Then, you loop over `CurrentMealPlan`, and want to pass each element over to the `DailyMealPlan` view:

```
DailyMealPlan(DailyMealPlan: currentDay))
```

That's also completely fine. So where does the `CurrentMealPlan is not in scope` error come from? It's this line:

```
var DailyMealPlan: Day = CurrentMealPlan[index] /// NO!
```

Remember, you declared `CurrentMealPlan` inside the parent view, *not* the `DailyMealPlan` view. That means the `DailyMealPlan` view can't access `CurrentMealPlan`.

However, the `DailyMealPlan` view **does not** need to access `CurrentMealPlan`. Back in the parent view, you're already looping through `CurrentMealPlan` and passing in each `currentDay` over to the `DailyMealPlan` view.

So, all you need to do is define the type of the `DailyMealPlan` property:

```
struct DailyMealPlan: View {
   var DailyMealPlan: Day /// here!
   ...
}
```

This lets the compiler know that `var DailyMealPlan` takes in a `Day`.

Comment: @MattYoung Also worth nothing that having a `DailyMealPlan` (`View`) with a `DailyMealPlan` property of type `Day` is *super* confusing. I'd suggest renaming the former to `DailyMealPlanView` and the property to `var day: Day` (note the lowercase `d`)

Comment: @jnpdx completely agree, just edited my answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a MVVM approach, each screen view should have it's own view model (which should be a class extending a base view model or protocol) which you pass when you create the view.

In your case you should have:

```
protocol BaseViewModel {
}

class DailyMealPlanViewModel: BaseViewModel {
 @Published var day: Day

}
```

in the above I also added *day* as @Published so any changes on that will refresh the view, if the *day* never changes you can remove @Published.

in your view:

```
struct DailyMealPlan: View {
 @StateObject var viewModel: DailyMealPlanViewModel
 ...
 ...
```

And when navigating:

```
NavigationLink(
      destination: DailyMealPlan(viewModel: DailyMealPlanViewModel(day: currentDay))
    ...
    ...
```